# Magsafe 1 Charger to Replace Magsafe 2 Charger

Tags: magsafe

My current Magsafe 2 charger broker, and I was wondering if my other Magsafe 1 charger can replace this Magsafe 2 charger?

Answer (score 2):

It can, but you will need a Magsafe 1 to 2 adapter. [Apple store](http://store.apple.com/us/product/MD504LL/A/magsafe-to-magsafe-2-converter?fnode=5a)